# Can't pass parameters from Ionic 2 to Polymer

Tags: angular, polymer, ionic2

I have a Polymer component that works great when called from a simple index.html page, but when I try to use it in an Ionic 2 page the parameters are not passing.

Here's the parameter declaration:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: "pnet-timeline",
    properties: {
      tlStartDate: String,
      tlDurationSecs: {
        type: Number,
        value: 86400
      },
      userId: {
        type: String,
        value: null
      },
      tlTitle: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Unknown'
      }
    },
```

The component works great when I call it from a simple index.html file like this:

```
  <pnet-timeline user-id="lowjam" tl-start-date="2016-02-29T00:00:00.000-0600" tl-duration-secs="86400" tl-title="Trip Planning"></pnet-timeline>
```

However, when I put that exact same tag into an Ionic 2 page the parameters are not passed to Polymer. Instead they are all set to their default value when Polymer runs. Polymer is certainly running though, I can see the component on the page and interact with it, but it doesn't have its parameters.

I'm not sure if this is something about Ionic 2 or (more likely) Angular 2, but it has me stumped right now.

Comment: More info on this. It looks like the properties are populated with correct values after `ready` executes. Until then, they have default values. Writing parameters out to the console immediately and then once per second shows default values and then consistent correct values following that.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. After reading [this excellent article on some of the finer points of Points of Polymer](https://github.com/kbenjamin/polymer-issues) I realized that properties are not fully loaded when `ready` is executed.

After playing around with observers and `this.async` I have a working solution for my app. Long story short, use `this.async` for initialization code and watch updates in an observer.

Thanks to [Ken Benjamin](https://github.com/kbenjamin) for the extremely useful Polymer write up!